# Posts on home page displaying excerpts from other posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a strange problem. I created a custom home page template to pull the latest 5 posts from two different categories into the layout (see "Learn and "Play" columns).

http://sensoryrevolution.com.s177767.gridserver.com/

I'm pulling in 4 fields through a custom query I copied+pasted from this very site:

- Post thumbnail
- Permalink
- Post title
- Excerpt

Only the excerpt is wrong. It's displaying the excerpt from the blog post above it.

Here's the code I'm using to pull this in. The weird thing is that it was working, and now it's broken. I've backed out some other custom code I had that was limiting the number of characters in the excerpt, so this is purely `the_excerpt()` working its magic.

```
<?php $posts = get_posts('category=213&orderby=desc&numberposts=5'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_post_thumbnail('blog-large'); ?></a>
    <p><?php the_excerpt() ?><?php // echo excerpt(22) ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

This is driving me crazy! Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: So can we see what the function the_excerpt() returns? What it does?

Comment: have you tried closing all function calls with `;`? Mite have an effect on it. Also, in these cases I would try using all these functions with the "get" affix in front, so for `the_excerpt()` use `get_the_excerpt()` by assigning it to a variable, ie - `$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();` and then `echo $excerpt;`. Then you can begin to determine the root of your issue. Alternatively, try just dumping the entire array on page like so - `var_dump($posts);` so you can get a view of what is being called in and determine from there the cause of this excerpt mystery (your code here, or somewhere else).

Comment: @LauriElias 
The output of the_excerpt() is just simple HTML:
'<p>At Sensory Revolution ... Physics: Spacetime &amp; You (6.5) Sense &amp; Science Overview […]</p>'

Is this what you mean?

Comment: @zillaofthegods I added your suggestion `var_dump($posts);` and you can see the new output [here](http://sensoryrevolution.com.s177767.gridserver.com/). I am, unfortunately, not very advanced with PHP and so I don't know how to use your other suggestions to further diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [post excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) takes the excerpt from the excerpt field in wordpress. By default the excerpt field is not shown on wordpress single posts/pages in the admin backend. You can add it by clicking the "screen options" in the top right of the "add new" post/page (or custom pages). You can then input any text you would like as the excerpt.

As you can see by your var_dump, it is saying there is no excerpt in the post:

`" ["post_title"]=> string(14) "It Makes Sense" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0)`.

As stated before, `the_excerpt()` does not look for the excerpt in the main content body. If you don't feel like adding the excerpt field in the back end, you can do something like this:

`$content = get_the_content(); echo substr($content, 0, 20);`

This will output the first 20 characters of the string (which is the content of the page/post/custom post). Obviously you can do `40` or something like that as well, to appropriately output what you feel is the rite amount.

Happy coding!

Comment: I tried your code. It's pulling content in and truncating it, but now it's inserting content from the same single post into each post in the loop. Here's my implementation:`<?php $posts = get_posts('category=213&orderby=desc&numberposts=5'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_parent"><?php the_post_thumbnail('blog-large'); ?></a>
    <p><?php $content = get_the_content(); echo substr($content, 0, 100); ?> ...</p>
    <?php } ?>`

Comment: Also, I moved the output of `var_dump($posts);` to the middle column [here](http://sensoryrevolution.com.s177767.gridserver.com).

Comment: does every post have content?

Comment: Yes, every post has content.

Comment: So, my client has had another developer change the code entirely from what I originally asked this question about. What is the protocol for that, in terms of resolving the original question?